# Galaxy Tab 8.9 grabbing the wrong layout in my app

Tags: android, android-layout

A Galaxy Tab 8.9 which has 800x1280 pixels and at 170dpi was giving me some errors in my dev console on googleplay.  What it is doing is pulling layouts from my layout-port and layout-land and I am completely stumped.

Here is everything :

The phone that keeps getting the crash :

```
Galaxy Tab 8.9 (GT-P7310)
```

Error Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.JungleTimers}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030003
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1751)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1767)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1005)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030003
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2039)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:389)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:245)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780)
at joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.JungleTimers.onCreate(JungleTimers.java:68)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1715)
... 11 more
```

Here is line 68 in JungleTimers :

```
setContentView(R.layout.jungle_timers);
```

So I created an emulator that had 1280x800 mdpi to simulate that device.  What doesn't make sense to me is that I triple checked and I can see that I have a jungle_timers layout in my "layout-port" and "layout-sw600dp" so that resource file should be found.  Another thing I found weird is that this is pulling all layouts from my layout-port and layout-land when it should be doing the layout-sw600 since this device is at 800x1280 and at mdpi.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this was because I was using an API that was pre 3.2 which meant I couldn't use the "sw" layout folders.  A quick fix I found was to make layout folders such as /layout-large-land, /layout-large-port, /layout-xlarge-land, /layout-xlarge-port and this solved my issue.